# How to render an element in a matrix in react?

Tags: reactjs, matrix, render

So I know how to loop through an array and render an element in react. Now I want to render a matrix. I have a 4*3 matrix and want to render the square element based on the value in the matrix. 
For instance, board = [[0,2,3,0],[2,2,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]. The result should render a 4 * 4 board, made of smaller squares, with its corresponding value inside.

Comment: This is not really a react question... It's an algo question... If you show us what you've tried that didn't work we can help you... see how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: At that point, I was confused about both how to run the logic inside the jsx syntax and the algo part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create another loop inside your loop to render the sub arrays. If each element in the `board` array represents a row, you can wrap each row in a `div` to give it its own row and the cells with `span` to keep every cell in the same row inline.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    board: [[0, 2, 3, 0], [2, 2, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
  };

  render() {
    const { board } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {board.map((row, i) => (
          <div key={i}>
            {row.map((col, j) => (
              <span key={j}>{col}</span>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```